# Using CoordinatorLayout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello I am very new to android and I am implementing my first app. To my understanding so far a `CoordinatorLayout` is the equivalent of `MasterView` in ASP.NET or a Master/Parent Template.

If I am right then my question is how do I then load / include other layouts dynamically into this coordinator layout in my `activity_main.xml` using java code in my activity.

Comment: If possible you should just inflate your layout and not add everything at runtime yourself, also please be sure to ask specific questions and include what you did so far, since this question is rather broad

Comment: My question was rather specific, I would like to know how to include other layouts dynamically into a coordinator layout.

Comment: The answer is to use `viewGroup.addView(View)` method.

Comment: Alright thank you, will look into that. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to give an id to your `CoordinatorLayout` in layout xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.atcommobitech.sac.HomeActivity"
    android:id="@+id/my_main_layout">

    <!-- Empty -->

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

If you want to create view programatically and add it in your `CoordinatorLayout` view, then in your main Activity *onCreate()* method:

```
CoordinatorLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.my_main_layout);

layout.removeAllViews();    // clear all views.

// adding a text view in CoordinateLayout
TextView textView = new TextView(HomeActivity.this);

textView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

textView.setText("Text inside CoordinateLayout");

layout.addView(textView); // adding textView as child view of coordinate layout.
```

But above code is not considered as good practice. Please use following way to inflate view, if you want to dynamically create view in runtime.

**XML layout file.** *(text.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"/>
```

**Java Code** in your main activity

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

CoordinatorLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.my_main_layout);

layout.removeAllViews();    // clear all views.

TextView textView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.text, null);

layout.addView(textView); // adding textView as child view of coordinate layout.
```

Comment: Okay so basically what I would be doing now is instead of creating and starting a new intent I would be removing and adding views to the coordinator layout?

Comment: No. you are taking view absolutely wrong way, keep your views rigid in a xml file of your Activity or Fragment and change those Fragments or Activities as per your application requires.